# Images not stacking correctly in mobile view bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap with WordPress. I am updating a profile page that displays an image of a person and their title as text. I am using a simple loop. There are 4 profiles to display so I have set the following:

```
class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lr-3"
```

Everything displays properly however in mobile view `xs-6`, the third profile is not to the left but to the right causing an empty space where it should be.

```
    <?php
/*
Template Name: Committee
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="container">
 <div id="section" class="clearfix row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
     <h1>Committee</h1>

  <?php 
              $temp_query = $wp_query;

              query_posts(array(
                'category_name' => 'committee', 
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order' => 'desc',
                'paged'=> $paged,
                /*'posts_per_page' => 10,*/
                'perm'=>'readable'

              ));
              if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
            ?>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" id="artists-gallery">

             <a class="profile-img" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><img src="<?php the_field('image');?>" alt=""/></a>
                  <p><?php the_field('name');?></p>
                  <p><?php the_field('title');?></p>


                      <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">

                        <!-- Modal content-->
                          <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title"><?php the_title();?></h4>
                            </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                            <p><?php the_content();?></p>
                          </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </div><!--end of artists gallery-->
                  <?php endwhile;?>
<!--<div class="next-post"><?php next_posts_link('Next >') ?></div>
    <div class="prev-post"><?php previous_posts_link('< Previous') ?></div>-->

              <?php else : ?>

              <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no pages found.' ); ?></p>

           <?php endif; ?>

      </div>
  </div><!--end of section-->
</div><!--end of container-->
<?php get_footer(); ?>

    `.profile-img img {
  border-radius: 2.5px;
  border: 1px solid #da2777;
  margin: 5px 0 5px 0; }

#artists-gallery img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto; }`
```

[full width lr 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9Gml.png)

[mobile view xs-6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1XXw.png)

Comment: can you add more of your CSS code and your html code so we can better understand whats going on

Comment: Could you put your code online ? Maybe, in JsFiddle or others ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess it's because your profiles are different heights. It looks to me like profile 1 is taller than profile 2, which is confusing bootstrap grid a bit due to the way floating works.

You can rectify it by either ensuring the profiles are all the same height, or using a different layout tool like Masonry.

Comment: Ok thanks for that, I have solved it by changing the img height from auto to 156px.